# How do I add photos to existing lightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I made a lightbox2 gallery a year ago for a friend following a tutorial online. She now wants to add photos to her existing gallery and I thought I could just add/delete jpgs from the directory as needed. I thought wrong. I only know HTML so modifying js code is doable, I just need help on what to do. Anyone able to help, please?

The gallery can be viewed here:

http://priestessanddeer.com/gallery/index.html

I'd also be open to buying/downloading a program to automatically set up the gallery - any suggestions?

Thanks so much for your time! Happy 2015!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I understand completely, but I seriously don't know which part of any code to post here. I'll go elsewhere.